# Linq returns a list through a series of filters

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to write a linq query that returns me a list of open orders  , then:

```
List<Order> GetOpenOrder(string shopId, string codeCustomer)
```

which returns a list of orders in the open status: opened by a store for the same customer.
I find The field CodeCustomer  through the property `OrderCustomer`, the field of `shopId` through `Order`. 
To retrieve the latest status of an order I refer to the property LastStatus  within the proxy class PxOrder. 
To retrieve the  id of the status open I refer `PxStatus.OpenStatusId` .

The property `LastStatus` in the Proxy class `PXOrder` is as follows:

```
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(Annotation), Name = "Order_Status")]
public string LastStatus
{
    get
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_lastStatus))
        {
            OrderStatus status = OrderStatus.OrderByDescending(x => x.StatusDate).FirstOrDefault();

            if (status != null)
            {
                string iso639 = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
                TextLanguage statusLanguage = status.Status.Text.TextLanguage.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Language.Iso639.ToLower() == iso639.ToLower());

                _lastStatus = statusLanguage != null ? statusLanguage.TextLanguageValue : string.Empty;
            }
            else
                _lastStatus = string.Empty;
        }

        return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(_lastStatus.ToLower());
     }
}
```

In the method `GetOpenOrder` I wrote the following query:

```
long openStatusId = new Status().OpenStatusId;

var list = Filter(x => x.ShopId == shopId  && x.OrderCustomer.Any(y => x.OrderCustomer.Any== codeCustomer) && x.LastStatus == ......;
return list.ToList();
```

**My problem is the last condition on LastStatus, that is, how to filter for the open status.** 
Thanks for any tip.

Comment: LastStatus is a string, what is its contents when an order is open?

Comment: Yes Last status is a string, returns the most recently order' status : could be  'open' or 'close' ...

Comment: Then simply do x.LastStatus == "open"

Comment: I should use the openStatusid for the filter with LastStatus. Order has a navigation property on OrderStatus and this has a navigation property Status , then status with Text. Text has fields Textid ,TextVAlue and textLanguage